# Pass in a state attribute to a React Native card title attribute

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have the follwoing code:

```
state = {
  displayName: "",
  email: ""
};

state2 = {
  test: "test"
};

componentDidMount() {
  const { displayName, email } = firebase.auth().currentUser;
  this.setState({ displayName, email })
}

render() {
  return (
    <View>
    <Card title={this.state.email}> // this does not work
      <Text>{this.state.email}</Text> // this works
      <Text>{this.state.displayName}</Text> // this works
    </Card>
  </View>
);
}
```

My question is why is it that when I put **this.state2.test** as a title attribute for the card, the card title is displayed properly but when I change it to **this.state.email** or **this.state.displayName** I get the following error: **Text strings must be rendered within a  component.**

Comment: Maybe try to call .toString on the email so : title={this.state.email.toString()}

Comment: Where is `Card` from? What does that implementation look like

Comment: @yesIamFaded Sorry forgot to mention that I tried that. No luck though

Comment: @DonovanHiland Card is one of the default React Components

Comment: how does response look like ? so this.state.email? because Card if taken from React Native Elements accepts a string or a component. Also Card is not a React Native component maybe React but not RN

Comment: It could be because the `currentUser` is not available right away when the app loads you could use `onAuthStateChanged` to listen when the user is authenticated.

Comment: @fayeed I tried `title={this.state.email != null ? this.state.email.toString() : "Hi" }` but no luck

Comment: @yesIamFaded what response? yes it is a React component

Comment: `componentDidMount` only run once when the screen loads so even if the `currentUser` is available later on like 1 or 2 seconds later it is not updated.

Comment: @fayeed when I do `<Text>{this.state.email}</Text>` it works though it's just the title

Comment: @ceebeeel where are you importing `Card` from? Can you show that import line?

Comment: @DonovanHiland `import { Card, Button, Text } from "react-native-elements";`

Comment: Have you tried passing a Text component inside title instead of passing a plain string?

Comment: @AnusKaleem can you show an example?

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question boils down to: Why does `"test"` work as the title to `Card` but `""` does not.

The answer lies in the source code for the `Card` component. The line of code that handles the title looks more or less like this (component condensed for brevity):

```js
<View>
  {title === "" || React.isValidElement(title)
    ? title
    : title &&
      title.length && (
        // ... display title if it's a string
      )}
</View>
```

The problem with this code is that if the title is an empty string, then it's going to render that empty string directly inside of a `View`. When strings are rendered outside of a `Text` component you get the error you described: **Text strings must be rendered within a component**

This seems like something that could be brought up to the maintainers of the library as a bug. The simplest workaround would be to pass in null instead of an empty string:

```
<Card title={this.state.email || null}>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that returns a Text component containing your desired title and use that function in title prop, of Card Component, instead of the plain string.

```
getTitle(title) {
    return(<Text>title</Text>)
}
```

Use this function in your Card Component.

```
render() {
  return (
    <View>
    <Card title={this.getTitle(this.state.email)}> //Instead of using plain string try using helper function declared above instead. 
      <Text>{this.state.email}</Text>
      <Text>{this.state.displayName}</Text>
    </Card>
  </View>
);
}
```